# Why CROSS APPLY and INNER JOIN returns different result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, cross-apply

Why using cross apply return extra row. Isn't it should work similar to INNER JOIN?
The result I'd expect is

```
QuoteID  controlNo  etc            MaxQuoteID   COntrolNo
10101     1111     something15     10101        1111
```

**Sample Data:**

```
-- create first example table
drop table if exists #test1
create table #test1 (QuoteID int, controlNo int, etc varchar(100))
insert into #test1 values 
(1111, 1111,'something1'),
(10101, 1111,'something15'),
(2222, 2222,'something2'),
(3333, 3333,'something3'),
(3333, 30303,'something35'),
(4444, 4444,'something4')
select * from #test1

--create second example table
drop table if exists #test2
create table #test2 (QuoteID int, ControlNo int)
insert into #test2 values 
(1111,1111),
(10101,1111)
select * from #test2

-- resutl query 1. This one works as expected
select * 
from #test1 t
inner join (select max(QuoteID) as MaxQuoteID, COntrolNo from #test2 group by ControlNo) tt ON t.QuoteID = tt.MaxQuoteID

-- But why this one doesnt work?
select * 
from #test1 t
cross apply 
(
-- subquery returns a single quoteid 10101, which is what I need
select max(QuoteID) as QuoteID
from #test2 tt
where tt.QuoteID = t.QuoteID
group by ControlNo
) a
```

Comment: Why shouldn't they return different results? You need to tell us why you have those expectations with justification per authoritative documentation if you want us to critique them. "We can't read your mind." Otherwise you are just asking for yet another presentation of the language giving no idea what you already don't understand. Also "extra row" & "should work similar to" are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the query are not the same.

In Query 1, you wanted the `max(QuoteID)` group by `controlNo`

In Query 2, you are getting the `max(QuoteID)` for each `controlNo`

If you wanted equivalent using `CROSS APPLY`, should be

```
select  * 
from    #test1 t
        cross apply 
        (
            select  max(tt.QuoteID) as QuoteID, tt.controlNo
            from    #test2 tt
            group by tt.controlNo
            having  max(QuoteID) = t.QuoteID
        ) a
```